The following build commands fail:Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-aqrljeugirxkfwedkgobaithyzlo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DemoQA.app/DemoQA
My project on React Native CLI . Version is 0.72 and Xcode version is 15.2. Failed Attempt to build the application.
My error is ::
The following build commands fail:Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-aqrljeugirxkfwedkgobaithyzlo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DemoQA.app/DemoQA  (in target 'DemoQA' from project 'Demo')
My package file content command is like
"ios:qa": "yarn ios:bundle && yarn ios:run -- --scheme 'DemoQA'", "i

os:bundle": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --assets-dest ./ --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'",     

"ios:run": "cd ios && pod cache clean --all && pod install && react-native run-ios --simulator='iPhone 15 Pro'",

Pod file :
# Resolve react_native_pods.rb with node to allow for hoisting
require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
  'require.resolve(
    "react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb",
    {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
  )', __dir__]).strip

platform :ios, '15.2'

prepare_react_native_project!

# If you are using a `react-native-flipper` your iOS build will fail when `NO_FLIPPER=1` is set.
# because `react-native-flipper` depends on (FlipperKit,...) that will be excluded
#
# To fix this you can also exclude `react-native-flipper` using a `react-native.config.js`
# ```js
# module.exports = {
#   dependencies: {
#     ...(process.env.NO_FLIPPER ? { 'react-native-flipper': { platforms: { ios: null } } } : {}),
# ```
flipper_config = ENV['NO_FLIPPER'] == "1" ? FlipperConfiguration.disabled : FlipperConfiguration.enabled

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

target 'Demo' do
  # pod 'RNAzureNotificationHub', :podspec => '../../../node_modules/react-native-azurenotificationhub/RNAzureNotificationHub.podspec'
  config = use_native_modules!
  # use_modular_headers!
  # permissions_path = '../../../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  # pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true # if you're using firebase
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'RNPermissions', :path => '../../../node_modules/react-native-permissions'
  permissions_path = '../../../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera"

  #pod 'binah-react-native-sdk',  :path => '../../../node_modules/binah-react-native-sdk'


  # Flags change depending on the env values.
  flags = get_default_flags()

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # Hermes is now enabled by default. Disable by setting this flag to false.
    :hermes_enabled => flags[:hermes_enabled],
    :fabric_enabled => flags[:fabric_enabled],
    # Enables Flipper.
    #
    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
    # you should disable the next line.
    # :flipper_configuration => flipper_config,
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

 
  
  target 'DemoDevelopment' do
    # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for DemoDevelopment
  
  end
  
  target 'DemoQA' do
    # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks

    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for DemoDevelopment
  
  end
  
  target 'DemoProduction' do
    # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
    inherit! :complete
  
    # Pods for DemoProduction
  
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false
    )
    
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
      if t.name.start_with?("AEP")
        t.build_configurations.each do |bc|
          bc.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] = '$(inherited) -no-verify-emitted-module-interface'
        end
      end
    end
    __apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
  end
end


Please give me a resolution regarding on this.
Please give me a resolution regarding on this. Solving issues.
